# Instrumentation for AsyncRestTemplate to resolve hostnames using DiscoveryClient

Tags: java, spring-cloud

While [spring-cloud-commons](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/) project provides a convenient way to instrument a `RestTemplate` with service names resolution from service discovery (by marking with `@LoadBalanced` annotation). The same way doesn't work for the `AsyncRestTemplate`.

In order to solve it, I had to write my own code which is specific to the underlying implementation of the asynchronous framework that used for HTTP communication. In my case it was the [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/index.html) project.

```
public class ServiceDiscoveryAwareRoutePlanner implements HttpRoutePlanner {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServiceDiscoveryAwareRoutePlanner.class);

    private final DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;

    public ServiceDiscoveryAwareRoutePlanner(DiscoveryClient discoveryClient) {
        this.discoveryClient = Objects.requireNonNull(discoveryClient, "discoveryClient");
    }

    @Override
    public HttpRoute determineRoute(HttpHost httpHost, HttpRequest httpRequest, HttpContext httpContext) throws HttpException {

        List<ServiceInstance> serviceInstances = discoveryClient.getInstances(httpHost.getHostName());
        if ( !serviceInstances.isEmpty() ){
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int serviceInstanceCount = serviceInstances.size();
            ServiceInstance si = serviceInstances.get(rnd.nextInt(serviceInstanceCount));
            LOGGER.debug("Replacing hostname: {} to address from service discovery: {}", httpHost.getHostName(), si.getUri());
            return new HttpRoute(new HttpHost(si.getHost(), si.getPort(), si.isSecure() ? "https" : "http"));
        } else {
            return new HttpRoute(httpHost);
        }
    }
}
```

Any plans to support similar behavior as with `RestTemplate` & `@LoadBalanced` annotation for `AsyncRestTemplate`?